# Extracting a string from a file name

Tags: sed, awk, sh

My script takes a file name in the form R#TYPE.TXT (# is a number and TYPE is two or three characters).
I want my script to give me TYPE. What should I do to get it? Guess I need to use awk and sed.

I'm using /bin/sh (which is a requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use awk

```
$ echo R1CcC.TXT | awk '{sub(/.*[0-9]/,"");sub(".TXT","")}{print}'
CcC
```

or

```
$ echo R1CcC.TXT | awk '{gsub(/.*[0-9]|\.TXT$/,"");print}'
CcC
```

and if sed is really what you want

```
$ echo R9XXX.TXT | sed 's/R[0-9]\(.*\)\.TXT/\1/'
XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
$ echo R3cf.txt | sed "s/.[0-9]\(.*\)\..*/\1/"

cf
```

If txt is always upper case and the filename always starts with R you could do something like.

```
$ echo R3cf.txt | sed "s/R[0-9]\(.*\)\.TXT/\1/"
```

Comment: If I use you example, I get sed: -e expression #1, char 20: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

I rewrite it to: sed "s/R1\(.*\)\.TXT/\1/"

Comment: I believe that if you write it RegEx like that your file name is going to have to start with "R1". Whats your "uname -a"?

Comment: upps, took the wrong code.
Should be sed "s/R[0-9]\(.*\)\.TXT/\1/"

Answer (score 0):

You can use just the shell (depending what shell your `bin/sh` is:

```
f=R9ABC.TXT
f="${f%.TXT}"       # remove the extension
type="${f#R[0-9]}"  # remove the first bit
echo "$type"        # ==> ABC
```

Comment: On the old unix system I code for I get "bad substitution" when I type f="${f%.TXT}"