# How to take string from a file name and use it as an argument

Tags: bash, shell

If a file name is in this format

```
assignment_number_username_filename.extension
```

Ex.

```
assignment_01_ssaha_homework1.txt
```

I need to extract just the username to use it in the rest of the script.

How do I take just the username and use it as an argument.

This is close to what I'm looking for but not exactly:

[Extracting a string from a file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999682/extracting-a-string-from-a-file-name)

if someone could explain how sed works in that scenario that would be just as helpful!

Here's what I have so far; I haven't used `cut` in a while so I'm getting error messages while trying to refresh myself.

```
 #!/bin/sh 
 a = $1
 grep $a /home | cut -c 1,2,4,5 echo $a`
```

Comment: Iv'e been stuck on trying to this part the rest of the code is just making new directories with the then extracted usernames and moving files containing those user names to the associated directories.do you know of a good link to an explanation of how to use the sed command?

Comment: Are you simply looking to extract the 3rd word from a string?  Look at the `cut` command.

Comment: yes thats the main issue, I just need to be able to use it later to do what I described in my comment below Jeremy D. and can it cut the extension out as well?

Comment: if you want to use cut:
`username = $(echo $filename | cut -d'_' -f 3`
Can't think of any simpler. -d is used to set delimeter to '_' and -f to choose column 3

Comment: Note that this is wrong: `a = $1` -- you are not allowed to put spaces around the equal sign. Do this: `a=$1`. If you put spaces, the shell will try to execute the command `a` with arguments `=` and `$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need command substitution, plus `echo` plus `sed`.  You need to know that `sed` regular expressions can remember portions of the match.  And you need to know basic regular expressions.  In context, this adds up to:

```
filename="assignment_01_ssaha_homework1.txt"

username=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_\([^_]*\)_[^.]*\.[^.]*$/\1/')
```

The `$(...)` notation is command substitution.  The commands in between the parentheses are run and the output is captured as a string.  In this case, the string is assigned to the variable `username`.

In the `sed` command, the overall command applies a particular substitution (`s/match/replace/`) operation to each line of input (here, that will be one line).  The `[^_]*` components of the regular expression match a sequence of (zero or more) non-underscores.  The `\(...\)` part remembers the enclosed regex (the third sequence of non-underscores, aka the user name).  The switch to `[^.]*` at the end recognizes the change in delimiter from underscore to dot.  The replacement text `\1` replaces the entire name with the remembered part of the pattern.  In general, you can have several remembered subsections of the pattern.  If the file name does not match the pattern, you'll get the input as output.

In `bash`, there are ways of avoiding the `echo`; you might well be able to use some of the more esoteric (meaning 'not available in other shells') mechanisms to extract the data.  That will work on the majority of modern POSIX-derived shells (Korn, Bash, and others).

Comment: thank you very much, is it safe to replace  `filename="assignment_01_ssaha_homework1.txt"` with a command line argument?

Comment: @AlecWiese: Of course; I was just making sure that you saw the name I was working with.  Also pointing out a probable problem in the question where you specify underscores separating components but then don't show underscores in the example name.  If formatting was the problem, remember to indent the example by (at least) 4 spaces to get 'code' formatting (constant width font and underscores as underscores).

Comment: yes the underscores are necessary, I dont know why I forgot them in my op. thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
filename="assignment_01_ssaha_homework1.txt"

username=$(echo "$file" | awk -F_ '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bash:

```
filename="assignment_01_ssaha_homework1.txt"
tmp=${filename%_*}
username=${tmp##*_}
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion